# unable to execute a .sh script with Jsch

Tags: java, shell, jsch

i'm trying to execute a script shell in a unix server from my java application (on my windows seven station) using the ssh api Jsch.

the script shell i'm using "start_lm" is a C binary.

this is the code i'm using (it's from the Jsch website exemples)

```
      try{
      JSch jsch=new JSch();  

      Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

      UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
      session.setUserInfo(ui);
      session.connect();

      String command="user/psi/start_lm";

      Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

      channel.setInputStream(null);

      ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

      InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

      channel.connect();

      while(true){

        if(channel.isClosed()){
          System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
          break;
        }
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
      }
      channel.disconnect();
      session.disconnect();
    }
```

the error i'm getting is

exit-status: -1 what does it mean

thanks for ure help.

Comment: How about reducing your code to a relevant sample? There's a LOT of fluff we don't need to see in there.

Comment: Can you execute the same command using command line `ssh user@host user/psi/start_lm`?

Answer (score 1):

There's the problem I believe

```
". ./start_lm.sh
```

It should be below provided script present in current directory

```
"./start_lm.sh
```

as exit status `127` says

```
127 "command not found" illegal_command
```

Comment: with this o get ksh: /start_lm.sh:  not found
exit-status: 1

Comment: Check my edit, is 'start_lm.sh' present in your current directory? If not mention the full path

Comment: i edited with the full path but now i get exit-status -1 is it ok? thanx for ure reply

Comment: success exit code is `0`. Again in your above code it should be `String command=". /user/psi/start_lm.sh";` instead `String command="user/psi/start_lm";`

Comment: [getExitStatus](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getExitStatus()) - Returns: the exitstatus returned by the remote command, or **-1, if the command not yet terminated (or this channel type has no command).** Are you sure the channel is opening properly?

Answer (score 0):

String command="/bin/sh /user/psi/start_lm.sh";

Please try the above, for jsch might be using an non-interactive shell.